# How many possible combinations of this stage given its a n * n grid?

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say you have n x n grid, and each square on the grid is either black or white. How many different combinations of this grid can exist?

I figured 9! would be for the grid, but I don't know how to incorporate the fact each tile can be 2 different things.

Comment: Is there anything *other* than black or white going on? Like numbered squares or something?

Comment: nope there isnt

Comment: 1. Where did the "9" come from? 2. Each square can be in two states. Start with one square. Two possibilities (B or W). Add a square (BB, BW,WB,WW) etc. Every new square simply doubles how many possibilities there are.

Comment: @Glen_b I think the OP meant 9 factorial. It still wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Michael Yes thanks, I saw the "!", but the question is what any specific number would be doing in a question about $n$.

Comment: @Glen_b nine has the letter $n$ in it twice. Therefore maybe he was thinking $9 = n^2$. I'm not sure where the factorial came from though. Any hypothesis?

Comment: I think it's more likely OP has a 3x3 problem to do for *homework* (which we should be careful not to provide explicit solutions of). The factorial is likely nothing but wild guessing in a problem to do with counting

Answer (score 4):

Each square can have one of two possible values. There are $n^2$ squares. Therefore the number of possibilities is $2^{n^2}$